# Does Xamarin support to develop apps for Windows surface and how well?

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios, cross-platform, xamarin.forms

I want to develop an app for Windows surface tablet and iOS mobile and iPad.

As I am a new user to Xamarin, when I created my first project,it shows 3 projects:-
hello.driod, hello.ios and hello.winPhone.

I have 3 questions based on this:-

**How will I be able to write the same code and share for windows 8.1 and iOS?**

and **whenever I drag and drop the elements to the UI page, will the same elements be copied to both windows and iOS simultaneously or I got to add them seperately?**

**Currently I dont have a MAC to connect to my PC. Can I write the code and and there while testing it, connect it to a MAC or should it be connected during the whole process?**

Please Help!

Answer (score 4):

1. Using the same code depends on how your structure your app.

You can go the native route where you can share the bulk of your logic by containing it in a shared / PCL project ([more on that here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/sharing_code_options/)), but have platform specific code for your UI.

For example, if you have a cross platform app targeting iOS and Android you would still create the UI in a storyboard for iOS and AXML files for Android. Any code you want to "connect" to your UI would be specific to that platform as you would use the platform APIs. Any code that is not platform specific (i.e., not calling iOS or Android APIs) can go in your shared / PCL project.

Or you can choose Xamarin.Forms which adds a layer of abstraction by allowing you to write the UI in XAML once and have it work on all platforms. The advantage is increased code sharing as now your UI is also shared. The downside is to utilise platform specific features you'll need to implement DependencyService or custom renderers. [Read more about Xamarin.Forms here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/).

2. As above, it depends. If you are going the native route, then no. If you are going with Xamarin.Forms, then you are using the same XAML code for the UI across platforms, but there is no drag and drop designer.
3. To build an iOS app you need to be connected to a Mac. You will also need to be connected to a Mac to use the iOS Designer.

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful reply! I've understood the answers for the the 2nd adn 3rd questions  but for the first one, I would love it if you can simplify it a bit more. Let me put it this way. I have used IDE's like Intel XDK , appcelarator ect where there was a UI screen in which I used to drag and drop the widgets and the code would be generated for that. The same thing, I could create a build for windows surface and iOS. So usinf Xamarin, can I do the same with/without the UI drag and drop options but write the C# code and build the packages for Windows surface and iOS ?

Comment: There is no wysiwyg designer that will allow you to create one UI and have it run on all platforms. The closest you will get to a single UI running on multiple platforms is with Xamarin.Forms, but you have to write the UI in code (XAML). If you go the native route you'll use the iOS designer provided by Xamarin for iOS apps (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/) and whatever designer is built in to Visual Studio for Windows apps.

Comment: So basically what you are telling is I have to code the UI widgets like button, calenders, etc separately for windows and iOS for the same application if I go to the native route? And also, is Xamarin.forms different than the native route? If i use xamarin.forms, can I create the UI screens same for all the platforms once? I am sorry to ask these many questions but I am just confused. Your help is deeply appreciated! If at all you feel annoyed, don't bother replying.

Comment: Yes that is what I have explained in my answer and comment. Xamarin.Forms allows you to do the UI once. Native you have to do the UI per platform.